# How to select all table elements inside a div parent node with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to select all `table` elements from a `div` parent node by using a customized function.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

url = 'https://www.salario.com.br/profissao/abacaxicultor-cbo-612510'

def getTables(url):

    url = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')

    div_component = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'td-post-content'})
    tables = div_component.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'listas'})

    return tables
```

However when applied as `getTables(url)` the output is an empty list `[]`.

I expect this function to return all html tables elements inside `div` node given specific his specific attributes.

How could I adjust this function?

Is there any other library I could use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking what the other commenters have said, and expanding on it.

Your `div_component` returns 1 element and doesn't contain tables, but using `find_all()` yeilds 8 elements:

```
len(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'td-post-content'}))
```

So you can't just use `find()` on a list you'll need to iterate through it to find a `div` that contains tables.

Another way to just go after the tables you want, you can just use

```
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'listas'})
```

where tables is a list with 6 elements. If you know which table you want, you can iterate through the tables until you find the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that "find" finds only the first such match.  The first td-post-content <div> does not contain any tables.  I think you want "findall".  Second, you can use CSS selectors with BeautifulSoup.  So, you can search for `soup.findall('div.td-post-content')` without using the attributes parameter.

Comment: css selectors soup.select('.td-post-content .listas')